# How to explore databases created by an embedded-Neo4j Java application and stored outside the /data directory?

Tags: neo4j

In the [Neo4j web administration tool](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tools-webadmin.html) (http://127.0.0.1:7474/webadmin/), I can only explore nodes and relationships created through this interface.

However, it doesn't show databases created by my Java applications which use embedded Neo4j and store databases outside the /data directory. How can I explore these databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Webadmin talked to the neo4j server instance. You can configure it using `config/neo4j-server.properties`, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you Peter. I found out that Gephi can be also useful for exploring these databases.

Comment: Yup, and feel free to bring the Neo4j Gephi plugin up to date if you are into it, https://gephi.org/plugins/neo4j-graph-database-support/

Comment: but what if I am experimenting with several distinct databases at the same time? Are we supposed to change the configuration file every time we want to explore a new database? Is there not an easier way to open several db browsers where each of them points to a distinct database?

Comment: Note that with Neo4j 3.0, the `neo4j-server.properties` file does not exist, and you instead have to use `neo4j.conf`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This question has got the right answer already but I ran into a silly problems so I'm posting this as a heads-up for other beginners.

An obvious thing to check is if you import the same version of Neo4j packages in your java code as the server you want to start. Opening a db created with a newer neo4j than the server may cause problems.

In console.log I was getting

> "Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1 Detected incorrectly
>   shut down database, performing recovery.."

and I could only debug the issue from data/graph.db/messages.log .