# Neo4J web console has stats for my embedded data, but cannot query it

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently evaluating Neo4J (2.0M3), and in an attempt to get some kind of visualisation and query-exploration (I haven't succeeded yet!), I switched from using the Test DB to an Embedded DB, and have a Server that I can start up when required.

I understand how to get my node and relationship data written to the data directory of my choice (via [How to explore databases created by an embedded-Neo4j Java application and stored outside the /data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057897/how-to-explore-databases-created-by-an-embedded-neo4j-java-application-and-store?rq=1)), and how to configure the Server/web console to point to that directory. Sure enough, the Dashboard **does show** the data counts I expect, but no Cypher query I try - not even the ones that work fine in my unit tests - return any nodes. Simple lookups by name and Id all fail.

Can anyone explain the inconsistency? This happens with a vanilla Server install, with data written to the default graph.db directory, as well as with different directories. The paths under 'Server Info' are all what I expetc to see.

Another thing I don't understand: why can I not have my own Server running, and create a `GraphDatabaseFactory`/`GraphDatabaseService` in code that will accept a server URI, which will allow me to use the standard Java API and see live updates in the web console without having to stop/start the server each time?

Comment: Andrew, is there a way to use the web admin to access an embedded database without the server?

Comment: I'm afraid I never solved it. In the end I dropped Neo4J and switched to Elasticsearch/Myrrix for what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your embedded java project to even start a server, see http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/05/23/enabling-neo4j-web-admin-tool-on-the-embedded-server-using-spring-data/

Comment: Thanks for the tip (I'll post a much quicker way to get started later) but it doesn't explain the problem I'm seeing. I can step through my test and see the Web console Dashboard counts go up as I create new Nodes, but the Ids and query results I see in my test don't match what I get in the Console at all. You'd think we were talking about two different datasets, yet Server Info > 'store_dir' matches what I passed to newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(...) - so I don't understand what Console is querying...